# Loop for editing shopify collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, shopify, smartcollection

I'm pretty new to Ruby scripting and have made a script to loop through product collections in Shopify to change the 'product match condition' on all collections but I can't seem to get it to work at all unless I specify the collection ID.

I keep getting an error saying "NoMethodError: undefined method `disjunctive=' for #" and I can't figure out why. The script I've written is below:

Failed collection loop:

```
count = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.count
page = 1 
while count > 0
  collectionsEdits = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(:all,:params => {:page=> page})
  collectionsEdits.disjunctive = 'true'
  collectionsEdits.save
  count = count - 50
  page = page + 1
end
```

Specific  collection ID:

```
collectionUpdate = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(437592964)
collectionUpdate.disjunctive = 'true'
collectionUpdate.save
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

API Documentation: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/smartcollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Shopify::SmartCollection is just an ActiveRecord model so I'd recommend you to write that like this:

```
ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.where(page: page).update_all(disjunctive: 'true')
```

P.S. in where clause you could provide any hash with your conditions

In your case error occurs because `find(:all)` return a collection but not a single instance that's why you cannot execute `disjunctive = 'true'`

So if you still want to write that your way do it like this:

```
count = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.count
page = 1 
while count > 0
  collectionsEdits = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(:all,:params => {:page=> page})
  collectionEdits.each do |collectionEdit|
    collectionEdit.disjunctive = 'true'
    collectionEdit.save
  end
  count = count - 50
  page = page + 1
end
```